# ZXing still has a memory leak. Even after releasing the Global Alloc

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, zxing

In this post: [Possible memory leak in Zxing's System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977278/possible-memory-leak-in-zxings-system-drawing-bitmap) a question is asked about a memory leak in the ZXing library. I've downloaded and amended the library with the free of the allocated memory. I've even introduced using(){} statements where applicable but I still get a memory leak.

I have a suspicion. Does the Marshal.Copy maybe do more then just copy the data from source to destination. Do I maybe also have to free the destination after the copy?

As you can see in the code below I even tried allocating the buffer only once and only reallocating it when an image larger than the previous one is requested, but that did not solve the problem.

Regards
Paul

My altered code:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace System.Drawing
{
public class Bitmap : IDisposable
{
    byte[] pixelData = new byte[0];
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    static IntPtr m_BufferPointer = default(IntPtr);
    static int m_Size;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reallocs the buffer when it becomes too small
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr ReallocBuffer(int size)
    {
        if(m_BufferPointer != default(IntPtr))
        {
            if(m_Size < size)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(m_BufferPointer);
                m_BufferPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_BufferPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        }

        m_Size = size;

        return m_BufferPointer;
    }

    public Bitmap (UIImage image)
    {
        UIImage backingImage = image;
        IntPtr rawData;

        using (CGImage imageRef = backingImage.CGImage)
        {
            width = imageRef.Width;
            height = imageRef.Height;

            using (CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB ())
            {
                int size = height * width * 4;
                rawData = ReallocBuffer(size); //Marshal.AllocHGlobal (height * width * 4);

                using (CGContext context = new CGBitmapContext (rawData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast))
                {
                    context.DrawImage (new RectangleF (0.0f, 0.0f, (float)width, (float)height), imageRef);

                    pixelData = new byte[height * width * 4];

                    Marshal.Copy (rawData, pixelData, 0, pixelData.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int CountCalled;
    private static int LastCountCalled = 20000000; //30411000;

    public Color GetPixel (int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {               
            CountCalled++;

            if (CountCalled - LastCountCalled > 100000)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine (CountCalled);
                LastCountCalled += 1000000;
            }

            byte bytesPerPixel = 4;
            int bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel;
            int rowOffset = y * bytesPerRow;
            int colOffset = x * bytesPerPixel;
            int pixelDataLoc = rowOffset + colOffset;

            Color ret = Color.FromArgb (pixelData [pixelDataLoc + 3], pixelData [pixelDataLoc + 0], pixelData [pixelDataLoc + 1], pixelData [pixelDataLoc + 2]);
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Req:  {0}x{1}", x, y);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation
    public void Dispose ()
    {
        pixelData = null;
        GC.Collect(0);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Just out of interest, how are you checking for the memory leak?

Comment: Well I do not. I get an out of memory on the Marshal.Copy after a while

Answer (score 2):

You need to free the native buffer, CGBitmapContext won't do it for you:

```
IntPtr rawData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (height * width * 4);

try {
    using (CGContext context = new CGBitmapContext (rawData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast))
    {
        context.DrawImage (new RectangleF (0.0f, 0.0f, (float)width, (float)height), imageRef);

        pixelData = new byte[height * width * 4];

        Marshal.Copy (rawData, pixelData, 0, pixelData.Length);
    }
} finally {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal (rawData);
}
```

*Updated according to Jonathan.Peppers try-finally suggestion in the comments*

Comment: A `try { } finally { Marshal.FreeHGlobal(rawData); }` around the entire code would be a good idea to add here, if an exception was thrown you'd get a leak.

Comment: @ Jonathan.Peppers +1 for pointing to the finally statement. That's really helpful.

Comment: Hi Rolf, did that already. Still got the out of memory on the copy. I've also added using where possible on other objects. Read below how that changed the outcome